# How to remove all the white space below the last element of a block?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'll start by saying that this may be a very silly question, but I'll ask it anyway.

I'm working on a site that has a header. The bottom of said header is filled with a navigation bar with four buttons. All is well and nice, *except* that the navigation bar is not at directly at the bottom of the header, but one pixel above the bottom.

This may be just a tiny little defect, but I aim to improve. Pray tell, how can I fix this?

The HTML is as follows:

```
<header>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" id= "home">Home</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#" id="sheets">Sheets</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#" id="export">Export</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#" id=  "help">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

And I use Sass, as follows:

```
$nav-height: 2em
$header-height: 3em + $nav-height
$nav-button-width: 20%
$nav-padding: (100% - $nav-button-width * 4) / 2

*
  padding: 0
  margin: 0

html
  font-size: 16px

header
  position: relative
  top: 0
  height: $header-height
  background-color: blue

#nav
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  height: $nav-height
  width: 100%
  list-style: none
  background-color: blue
  text-align: center

  li
    display: inline

  a
    padding: 0.33em
    display: inline-block
    width: $nav-button-width
    height: inherit
    text-align: center
    background-color: purple
    color: orange

    &:hover
      background-color: indigo
```

Comment: Try setting the margins and/or paddings on the ul to 0. That said, I'm curious how you can see that there's a one pixel space, with the header and the ul having the same background color.

Comment: Together with that set margin and padding to 0 of the *li* tags.

Comment: @MrLister , that's because the `ul` is blue, but every `li` is purple. @Krasimir , `margin` and `padding` are both set to 0. Everything is, unless stated otherwise beneath where it says `* margin: 0 padding: 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is silly. I never noticed. The `padding` on the `a` was slightly too small. I removed it and made it obsolete by adding `position: relative` to the `li` and `height: 100%` to the `a`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You use an id called "nav" to the navigation. And you added "absolute" position value to it. And you declared that this elements position from bottom is 0.

```
#nav
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  height: $nav-height
  width: 100%
  list-style: none
  background-color: blue
  text-align: center
```

You can change the bottom value to change the position from bottom. In this case use `bottom: 1px;`

Hope this works.

Comment: `bottom: 1px` would only make the gap *bigger*, which wouldn't solve much. `bottom: -1px` would work, but I'd still want to know *why* this happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the height on `#nav`.  There is no height on the descendant elements that have a background color, which gives it the illusion that it isn't sitting at the bottom of the header.  Remove the height (or move the height to the elements with a background color) and it works as you would expect.